# How to parse timestamp with milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I have a timestamp 1353954367108 . I'd like to parse this to a datetime object in Python. How can I do that?

Comment: If Python doesn't have call that specifically handles that, divide by 1000!

Comment: Under the assumption the timestamp is expressed as _ms_ not _s_, this is a duplicate ... but the question is more understandable than the original ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a duplicate if we assume your *timestamp* as expressed in 1/1000s ([Unix timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) are usually in *seconds*) In that case, the answer is [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1353954367108/1000.)
                      # don't forget the dot ^ to force floating point division!
datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 26, 19, 26, 7)
```

---

If your *timestamp* is really in *seconds*, well you have to find an other solution able to deal with dates in distant future!

Comment: to allow easy round-trip: `utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(millis // 1000).replace(microsecond=1000 * (millis % 1000))`